# Scrapy not returning text body of web page with my current syntax

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I am successfully using a recursive webscraper built with Scrapy to parse all the text in Wikipedia articles. However, I am trying to apply the same code to the website referenced in the code, but it is not returning any of the text body:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
import time


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goal3"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com"]
    download_delay = 1

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True, callback='parse_item')]
    #rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), 
                  #follow=True),
             #Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_item')
    #]
    #rules = [
        #Rule(
            #SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('Regions/252/Tournaments/2',)), 
            #callback='parse_item',
            #follow=True,
        #)
    #]
    def parse_item(self,response):
        self.log('A response from %s just arrived!' % response.url)
        scripts = response.selector.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
        for scripts in scripts:
            body = response.xpath('//p').extract()
            body2 = "".join(body)
            print remove_tags(body2).encode('utf-8')  


execute(['scrapy','crawl','goal3'])
```

A sample page I might like to view would be one such as this:

http://www.whoscored.com/Articles/pn4gahfw90kjwje-yx7ztq/Show/Player-Focus-Potential-Change-in-System-may-Convince-Vidal-to-Leave-Juventus
As I understand it, the code above should extract any text strings found on the page and join them together. The HTML mark up for the example page above, encapsulates text with `<p>` tags, so I am not sure why this is not working. Can anyone see an obvious reason why all I am getting returned is the page footer using this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bit of a mess inside the `parse_item()`. Here's the fixed version that gets the text from all the paragraphs (`p` tags) and joins it:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goal3"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com"]
    download_delay = 1

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True, callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self,response):
        paragraphs = response.selector.xpath("//p").extract()
        text = "".join(remove_tags(paragraph).encode('utf-8') for paragraph in paragraphs)
        print text
```

For [this page](http://www.whoscored.com/Articles/pn4gahfw90kjwje-yx7ztq/Show/Player-Focus-Potential-Change-in-System-may-Convince-Vidal-to-Leave-Juventus) it prints:

```
"There is no budget, there is money. We are in a very strong financial position. We can make big signings." Music to the ears of Manchester United fans as vice-chairman Ed Woodward confirmed the club can make big-money acquisitions in this very transfer window. In a bid to return to the summit of England’s top tier, Woodward has effectively given the green light to a spending spree that has supporters rubbing their hands with glee. Ander Herrara and Luke Shaw have arrived for a combined £59m already this summer and the carousel through the Old Trafford entrance door shows no sign of slowing down. Ángel Di María, Mats Hummels and Daley Blind, amongst others, have all been linked with a move to United, while reports suggesting midfield pitbull Arturo Vidal is set to join Louis van Gaal’s side refuse to die down.  "I’m still on holiday at the moment. Can I say I’m staying at Juve? I don’t know. On Monday I’ll talk to (Juventus manager, Massimili
...
 Contact Us | About Us | Glossary | Privacy Policy | WhoScored Ratings
            Copyright © 2014 WhoScored.com
```